# Why are pem2der and der2pem not inverses?

Tags: php

In the supplementary comments for [PHP's OpenSSL functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.openssl.php) there's this snippet

```
function pem2der($pem_data) {
   $begin = "CERTIFICATE-----";
   $end   = "-----END";
   $pem_data = substr($pem_data, strpos($pem_data, $begin)+strlen($begin));   
   $pem_data = substr($pem_data, 0, strpos($pem_data, $end));
   $der = base64_decode($pem_data);
   return $der;
}

function der2pem($der_data) {
   $pem = chunk_split(base64_encode($der_data), 64, "\n");
   $pem = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n".$pem."-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
   return $pem;
}
```

These functions aren't inverses. My test code:

```
$priv_key = ...;

print $priv; // dev data, of course

print der2pem (pem2der ($priv));
```

Prints

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIJQwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAS... (etc)
```

then

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
TEKEYMIIJQwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFA... (etc)
```

Note the second one has a `TEKEY` prefix. In hex that's `4c4284` which doesn't look significant.

Where did this come from?

Comment: It's not official PHP code. If you don't like it, perhaps write your own? I bet there's better support for what you want this to do now anyways

Answer (score 1):

These functions are only designed to handle certificates, not private keys. The reason the result is wrong is because the `pem2der` function is looking for the start of a certificate (`CERTIFICATE-----` from `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`). You're trying to decode a key starting with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`. The "TE KEY" part of the result comes from here: "-----BEGIN PRIVA**TE KEY**-----" and is a result of the functions not handling that header so the `substr` calls return the wrong result.

In theory, the functions should be very easy to modify to process private key files though.